# Lambda expression where... does not contain

Tags: c#, lambda

My database structure is as [image]
When a user answers a question, a record in the QuestionCounters table is inserted or updated.
Now i need to provide to the user the ability to check which questions are not answered yet.

That means the output should be All Questions excluding the records contained in the QuestionCounters.

How can i do that? I am really stuck

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the contents..

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you've got navigation properties set up properly in your data model, something like this should work:

```
db.Questions.Where(q => !q.QuestionCounters.Any())
```

If you don't have a `q.QuestionCounters` navigation property, something like this could work:

```
db.Questions.Where(q => !db.QuestionCounters.Any(qc => qc.QuestionsID == q.QuestionsID))
```

Comment: Thanks! great. i followed the second option since i needed also the member filtered: db.Questions.Where(q => !db.QuestionCounters.Any(qc => qc.QuestionsID == q.QuestionsID && qc.MemberID == User.Identity.GetUserId()))

Comment: @OrElse: You could also have filtered the navigation property: `...!q.QuestionCounters.Any(qc => qc.MemberID == ...))`